# Plotting correlation coefficient against regression coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation, data-visualization

I have samples taken in different places with yearly data for temperature and a measure of photosynthetic activity/biomass (NDVI). So for example for each sample I have ...

1. Year 2000 2001 2003
2. Temperature 12 10 13
3. Biomass measure 0.6 0.8 0.7

I have calculated the linear regression coefficient (slope) of the biomass measure against the year (using rows a and b), so the regression coefficient shows the trend in biomass over time.

I then calculated a correlation coefficient for the relationship between biomass measure and temperature (using rows b and c). The correlation coefficient of this shows me how strongly biomass correlates with temperature for that sample point.

Now I would like to plot the regression coefficient against the correlation coefficient for each sample. So I would like to compare biomass change over time with biomass relationship to temperature. If plotting these two against each other had a positive correlation I think it should show me that the areas had seen greater increases in biomass has a stronger correlation with temperature.

However, I have no idea if this is statistically sound! any clarification into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered making a 3D surface plot? If you don't have 3D surface modeling software, post a link to the data and I can give it a try.

Comment: What do you mean by a 3D surface plot? sounds interesting!

Comment: If "y=f(x)" is a 2D curve when plotted, then "z=f(x,y)" is a 3D surface when plotted. You might be able to find a (hopefully simple) surface equation of the form "biomass = f(year, temperature)" that would be sufficient for your needs. If you can post some data I can perform an equation search using my online surface fitting web site zunzun.com and see what turns up.